# Decouple restful path to controller, action and parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

What is the way to decouple restful path in terms of controller action and http method hash.

Lets take an example, `admin_profile_path`

```
# inside routes file
match '/admin/profile/something', :to => 'users#show', :as => :admin_profile
```

Now, If i am aware of `restful path` and wanted to `calculate controller & action` based on the path.. ??

I need something below -

```
`decouple(profile_path)` #=> {:controller => 'users', :action => 'show'}
```

Comment: I think looking into source code of mapping of routes will benefit me :)

Answer (score 0):

why? try to use more simple method. Rails is simple, not hard. What do you want to do?